# Check for duplicates in sqlite3 database and return error if any

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database file with multiple tables, each one with different values, what i want to do now is to check if a value already exists in any table when inserting it to the table and if it already exists returns an error or something.

This is because I'm doing a program t help nurses have a database with their patient and check if a patient has already been inserted into the database, I dont post any code because i'm gathering all the information needed before programming anything to avoid spaghetti code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a constraint to each or just one of your columns so I doesn't allow duplicates to be added

Like this:

```
CONSTRAINT <Constraint Name> UNIQUE (<column1>,<column2>)
```

Then in your code you could catch the SQL exception and return a custom message

Comment: Please provide a little more detail on what exactly you mean